# Matlab structure with Children that are arrays of structs, etc. - How do trace path to all children individually?

Tags: matlab, recursion, struct, tree

I have a Matlab structure, **A**, that has 3 fields.  The first field is **SignalName** and the third field is **Children**.  **Children** can either be empty or a Struct array with the same fields, and so on, to an arbitrary depth not immediately known to the user. **SignalName** is a character array which is the name of a signal.

I have written a recursive function (in Matlab) to retrieve all of the **SignalName** values for structures that have no **Children**, and it's pretty slick (I think), but I need to know the *absolute* path taken to arrive at said **SignalName**.  I cannot figure this out in Matlab.

As an example:

```
A.SignalName = 'Things'
A.Children = <22x1 struct>
A.Children(1).SignalName = 'Places'
A.Children(1).Children = [8x1 struct]
```

This goes on for an unknown depth, and the length of the struct arrays is not immediately known.  It is easy via recursion to 'dive' down and get all of the SignalNames belonging to Children with no further Children, but how do I trace the route I used to get there?  My function would ideally return results as a signal name, and the path taken to said signal.

In my experience with other languages, it seems like something like A* or Breadth-First might help, but I'm not exactly searching for something. I want simply to map every node and the path to it, and I'm not sure how to do that with the strange data-structure I'm given.

Thanks for any help you all can provide!

**EDIT:** I wanted to provide the code to hopefully shed light on my issue.  I can get the paths down to the deepest node, but any other nodes at that level leave me without a complete path to that specific location.  This is what I need help with.  I am using '*' as my delimiter for a regexp in my post-processing script to break up the strings in PATHS.

For two nodes at the same depth, I might get a full path like *'A.B.C.D.Signal1'* for the first node, but the second would give me a path of *'D.Signal2'*, when what I need is *'A.B.C.D.Signal2'*.  If the path was the same to the 'D' level with every signal, I would just copy the path over, but I have multiple branches in this struct from each level, and I go 4 or 5 levels deep.

```
function [NAMES,PATHS]=FindSignals(A,TMP,TMP2)

persistent SigName;
persistent path;
SigName = TMP;
path = TMP2;
if(~isempty(A.Children)) % If this struct has Children
    for i = 1:length(A.Children) % Iterate through the Children
        nextStruct = A.Children(i);
        path = strcat([path '*' A.SignalName]);
        [NAMES,PATHS] = FindSignals(nextStruct,SigName,path); % Recurse
    end
else % If this struct has no Children
    path = strcat([path '*' A.SignalName '*']); % Finish the path to Child
    SigName = char(SigName,A.SignalName); % Grab the signal name
    NAMES = SigName;
    PATHS = path;
end

end
```

Again, thanks for any help!

**EDIT**: 12/14/2015 - I'm still completely stuck on this.  Could anyone please take a peek at my source code above?  I am unsure how to tack on an absolute path to the recursive function call and allow it to be a full path for each node at the same depth, and then reset to the appropriate depth once I move up or down the 'tree'.  Thanks.

Comment: Because I'm too lazy to write my own I have used [`fieldnamesr`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33262-get-structure-field-names-in-recursive-manner) with success in the past. If you have written a recursive function to get to the lowest level children I don't understand why you can't store the path along the way.

Comment: Once I get down to the bottom, I could have the path to that Child, but I would not have a complete path for another child at the same level.  I need an absolute path for every child/node.  I worked this approach for some time and did some fancy post-processing to copy paths from one child to the next, but I ran into too many strange corner-cases doing this after the fact and couldn't find a smooth way to do it simply.  I thought there had to be another way. I tried fieldnamesr in the past, but ran into some issue with it... I'll try to remember why it didn't work for me.

Comment: Just an update: I've placed the source code for my function in the original post; hopefully this can help clarify the problem I'm having.